# How to remove a keylogger from MAC/how to reformat MAC to get rid of it?

Tags: malware, macos, keyloggers

I signed up to be a usability tester on a European site. I had to install software on my mac to complete a test. I had to use Disk Utility to install the dmg because just clicking it won't install. I think I installed a key logger. It is too good to be true to be pay for testing from home after I thought about it. I ran Malwarebytes on MAC and nothing was detected. I'm running Avast now. If I reformat the MAC will it remove it. How do I know I was infected with something. I thought the site was legit, but after 2nd thoughts I feel I might have installed malware. If I open another computer that uses my home WIFI will it infect the other computers? Please advise and help.

Comment: You should probably call a local computer technician to help you, because malware, especially keyloggers, aren't something to play around with unless you know what you're doing (not trying to be offensive).

Comment: Regarding your last question, yes, it would be irresponsible to connect your supposedly infected machine to any network/machine. In addition to that, don't plug in external drives. Definitely do disable your Internet connection.